# Offline installer for .Net 3.5 SP1 not working

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-server-2012

I downloaded a [big file of .Net 3.5 SP1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe).

Now when I try to install it on Windows Server 2012, I get the following screenshot:

[image]

Now this is a loop. When I try to install from Server Manager, I get installation cannot be done. It needs the installation disk.

Does that mean I can't install at all without the installation disk in presence?

Comment: Note: cross-posted on Server Fault at https://serverfault.com/questions/463616/offline-installer-for-net-3-5-sp1-not-working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your WSUS server is probobly getting in the way, or you just can't reach the Microsoft update site.

[Follow these directions.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782/en-us)  "Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair"  worked for me.

Comment: awesome! I wasted 4 hrs behind this!

Answer (score 2):

This is alternate solution when you don't have windows server installation disk

1. 1.On your local computer(not server), go to windows install directory(C:\Windows) and then find "WinSxS" directory.
2. Copy this folder to server
3. Open add roles and features wizard, go to features tab and check .Net Framework SP1.
4. Then bellow of this window click on "Specify Alternate Source Path" and in new window specify folder path that you coped early on the server.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this. We made it for ourselves if we need it in future.

STEPS:

- Create a bat file
- Copy this text into the bat file and save it:

  ```
  @echo To install .NET 3.5 SP1 you need to find the Windows 8.1 DVD Installer or the ISO file.
  @echo Please follow the steps below:
  @echo 1. Insert the DVD Installer or mount the ISO file."
  @echo 2. Open MyComputer and find out the drive letter of the DVD ROM that you just inserted DVD Disk or mounted ISO file."
  @echo off
  set /p DriveLetter="Please enter the letter of your DVD ROM: "

  Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:%DriveLetter%:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

  @echo off
  set /p DriveLetter="Press Enter to close"
  ```
- Run the bat file as Administrator by right click and click on Run As Administrator and rest should be self explanatory.

Comment: This is the correct DISM line to do the install. However, this doesn't actually help in an _offline_ installation situation (at least not in my recent experience). It will probably work as long as the machine has network capability. If it doesn't work however (likely, if you dont have internet access from that box) then try removing these SP's: KB2966826, KB2966827 and KB2966828, then rerun the DISM command. This fixed it for me on a non internet enabled box.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is too late, I want to share my experience. Hope this will help some -

My Windows Update was OK and I could not install .Net Framework 3.5 from Add roles and features wizard. The following two commands actually made my day -

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3ServiceFeatures /Source:%DriveLetter%:\sources\sxs

Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /Source:%DriveLetter%:\sources\sxs
```