# Jenkins windows node frequently disconnecting with ERROR: Message not found for errorCode: 0xC00000AC for wmi connection

Tags: windows, jenkins, wmi, jnlp, wmi-query

My Jenkins nodes are frequently disconnecting with below error

Windows nodes and connected via WMI method

My job nearly take 12 hours of time to complete , its a test job, download maven packages from artifactory.

Error Details

```
ERROR: Message not found for errorCode: 0xC00000AC
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Message not found for errorCode: 0xC00000AC
    at org.jinterop.winreg.smb.JIWinRegStub.winreg_OpenHKLM(JIWinRegStub.java:102)
    at hudson.util.jna.DotNet.isInstalled(DotNet.java:113)
    at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:286)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:294)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: All pipe instances are busy.
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:664)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:989)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
    at jcifs.smb.TransactNamedPipeOutputStream.<init>(TransactNamedPipeOutputStream.java:32)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbNamedPipe.getNamedPipeOutputStream(SmbNamedPipe.java:187)
    at rpc.ncacn_np.RpcTransport.attach(RpcTransport.java:91)
    at rpc.Stub.attach(Stub.java:104)
    at rpc.Stub.call(Stub.java:109)
    at org.jinterop.winreg.smb.JIWinRegStub.winreg_OpenHKLM(JIWinRegStub.java:100)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754417/how-to-run-jenkins-slave-on-windows-2012-r2-x64 <- 8 years old question, same error message, different resolutions, no idea if any of that would be helpful

Comment: It does fall over inside `DotNet.isInstalled` so maybe the bit about having dotnet installed is relevant.

Comment: (how did I get 8 years old? I can't math. But it's several years old.)

Comment: My job running successfully for multiple iterations , but suddenly its failing with this error , if it's issue with DotNet.isInstalled it has to be fail at starting of the job only. and I'm using 2.249.3 LTS version and windows 2010 enterprise edition