# Inno Setup: Need a standalone Installer for .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 for Windows Server 2012 R2 (no Internet and no DVD Installation Media)

Tags: .net, windows, inno-setup

I need your help. We have a Setup which we want to migrate from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 Server R2. In our setup we install .NET Framework 3.5 with File dotnetfx35.exe which is running fine on Windows Server 2008 R2. On Windows Server 2012 R2 this file is no working anymore(Error [Offline installer for .Net 3.5 SP1 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192244/offline-installer-for-net-3-5-sp1-not-working))

How can install or enable .NET Framework 3.5 (SP1) for Windows Server 2012 R2 without Internet and No Media Installation available by INNO SETUP or by Command Line, PowerShell? There is from Micrososft an Standalone Exe to Install on Windows Server 2012 R2??

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

to install the framework 3.5 in offline mode, Make sure you have the Windows Server 2012 R2 DVD or the source files to install the framework in offline mode.
use the following command:

Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:H:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

Where "H:\sources\sxs" is the path to your Windows DVD or the source.
If you prefer using the PowerShell, run the following command in PowerShell:
Install-WindowsFeature –name NET-Framework-Core –source H:\sources\sxs
This will enable the feature.

for standalone installer you can add "H:\sources\sxs" from Windows DVD to your installer and in run time extract it in temp folder and use the above command Line for enabling that.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot of your help. I will try to do the steps described by you.